# Recommendation engine in cypher Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to cypher. I have a table with customers bought materials. my target is to create recommendation to customers. lets say A bought 1,2,3 products and B bought 1,3 products, here I want to recommend product 2 to B customer. kindly suggest

```
MATCH (p:Rbe{endUser:1012444})-[:BOUGHT]->(p:material)<-[:BOUGHT]-(peer:endUser)-[:BOUGHT]->(reco:material)
WHERE not (p)-[:BOUGHT]->(reco) 
RETURN reco as Recommendation
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: what is your question? You already have some sort of recommendation query

Comment: I imported a table having 50k records from sql server and trying to create relationship between customer and material bought to see in graph model and also suggest other materials as recommendation engine